# How to use order by in Wordpress via WP_Query?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to put a `order by`  inside a wp_query but I can't get it to work.

What is wrong?

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'cat='.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'select',1).'&orderby=menu_order');
```

Comment: That's the way to use it, what does `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'select',1)` returns ? Also you could pass an args array as parameter to be more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you meant:

```
$query = new WP_Query(
            'cat'     = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'select',1),
            'orderby' = 'menu_order',
            'order'   = 'asc'
         );
```

your should pass as an array, for better readability. Also add how to order.

Answer (score 1):

Check this if it is working for you:

```
$args = array(
'cat' => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'select', 1),
'orderby' => 'menu_order',
'order' => 'DESC');
WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Looks like WP_Query needs an array for multiple arguments: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Dear Harpreet and Michiel, Thanks for your help but i have done by my self I did $query = new WP_Query( 'cat='.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'select',1).'&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC');